# Please help me with this page with IE 7/8

Tags: css, alignment, css-float

http://site2.ewart.library.ubc.ca/

When I use my IE 7 or IE 8 to visit this page, the text below the carousel image is aligned to the right, until I manually navigate images through clicking the left & right button or the dots.

At the same time, the left & right buttons are placed under the dots, while it should be on the right of the dots.

(this page works properly in FF).

I also got some feedback from folks saying that this page works correctly in their IE 8. So I am totally confused.

Thanks.

(Please see attached screenshot from my IE 8)

[image]

Comment: Try to change the height of the bloc: Dots = 32px and Buttons = 38px.
You have also a padding to the "left" and "right", try to remove it, because the width is perhaps to wide.

Answer (score 0):

Give "wrapper" a size in pixels, not PERCENT, such as `width:450px`